# Double Quotes in C#

Tags: c#

this program is downloading videos... -o to custom save location

```
            var mainForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Single();
            string urlBoxText2 = mainForm.Controls["URL_BOX"].Text;
            string text = "C:/Program Files/Sycho_DL/Downloader.exe -f 18 -o "C:\%(title)s.%(ext)s" ";
            string me2me = text + urlBoxText2;

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Downloader.exe";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = me2me;
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
```

- Look at string text...[Gives this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOFRz.png)
- why I can't put Double Quotes "" from start to end?
- Note: the code will work if I typed it in txt file and used File. ReadAllText
- I tried to make 'C:%(title)s.%(ext)s' with single quates but program won't download...

Comment: Double quotes are used to denote strings in C#. So if you need to use a double quote within a string, you need to escape it. If you research how to put a double quote in a C# string, you're sure to find helpful information. Make sure you adequately research your problem before asking a question here.

Comment: It can't tell the difference between the double quotes that define the string and those within it.  Escape them with ``\"`` or use a verbatim string (`@"Your text here"`).

Comment: @LanceU.Matthews (@"Your text here") this didn't work.......
how to use \" ?

Answer (score 0):

To add double quotes in string c# is by doubling them. Example:

```
var someStr = "this is ""me""";
```

Comment: You double them inside a verbatim string literal, and escape them inside a regular string literal.

Comment: @hndrbs didn't work.

Comment: ah, thanks @LanceU.Matthews. Forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "C:/Program Files/Sycho_DL/Downloader.exe -f 18 -o  \"C:/%(title)s.%(ext)s\" ";
```

Fixed thanks.